# Binding multiple objects in a Spring form

Tags: spring, spring-form

I have problems with getting my JSP view right. What I intend to do is to send a List that contains questions and each question object is a text field and a List with alternatives.

My intention is to be able to edit multiple questions (both to be able to edit the text/name of the question and edit the containing alternatives).

My backing object is now sending an List question.

Here is my JSP which are failing with invalid property of bean class.

```
        <form:form commandName="question">
        <form:errors path="*">
            <fieldset class="stdframe">
                <legend>Question</legend>
            </fieldset>
        </form:errors>

        <div class="stdframe">
            <c:forEach var="q" items = "${question}" varStatus = "s">           
                <p><b>Question:</b></p>
                <p><form:input size="67" path="${q.text}"/></p>
                <br/>
                ${q.text}
                <ul>
                    <c:forEach var="alternative" items = "${q.alternatives}" varStatus = "t">
                        ${alternative.text}
                        <li><form:input path = "${alternative[$t.index].text}" /></li>
                    </c:forEach>
                </ul>
                <br/>
            </c:forEach>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Save" />
                <input type="button" class="button" onClick="back()" value="Back"/>
        </div>
</form:form>
```

I have tried both `${q.text}` and `${q[$s.index].text}`. When I just print `${q.text}` it shows the correct text for the question object. Same goes for alternative.

What can I do to correctly bind the form to the objects?

In addition when I store an object which contains a list of other object, will the list be stored itself in the database?

Comment: What seems to be the problem is the binding for the question. I can't get the path to be correct. I want to have for each question object to bind at the text field. 
It works when I just send one Question object and path is "text", but will not work when I send a List<Question>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to wrap your List in a simple object with the List as a field:

```
class MyListWrapper { List questions; } // etc.
```

If you use that as your command/form object, you should be able to do something like this in the JSP:

```
<form:form commandName="wrapper">
// ... 
        <c:forEach var="q" items = "${wrapper.questions}" varStatus = "s">
           <p><b>Question:</b></p>
            <p><form:input size="67" path="questions[${s.index}].text"/></p>
// ... 
               <c:forEach var="alternative" items = "${q.alternatives}" varStatus = "t">
                    ${alternative.text}
                    <li><form:input path = "questions[${s.index}].alternatives[${t.index}].text" /></li>
```